# adding default parameters of the function as result of other function

Tags: php, function, parameters, yii2

Hi I have question it is possible to adding default parameters of the function as result of other function? For example:

```
static function addParameter(){
return rand(10,100)
}

function doSomething($year=$this->addParameter()) or 
function doSomething($year=class::addParameter())
```

I need to pass actual year and month to my function. When i pass

> function($month=3, $year=2016)

it work then but i not want to write this from hand but want to use function or something to always return actual month and year.

Comment: Not sure I get what you are trying to achieve, but do you mean default values?

Comment: default mean when function start and noone switch her parameters she work on parameters which was write in her by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php states that:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

You can use default null value (if normally function does not take one) and check if parameter is null, then get value from function:

```
function testfun($testparam = null) {
    if ($testparam == null) $testparam = myclass::funToReturnParam();
    // Rest of function body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can implement it like this

```
<?php
class Core {
    static function addParameter(){
       return rand(10,100);
    }
}

$core  = new Core();

function doSomething($rand){
    echo 'this is rand '.$rand;
    }

doSomething(Core::addParameter());
```

You can change the function defination according to your requirement.
hope it helps :)

Comment: but this is when i started to work with function i want to know it is possibe to pass parameters when i write this function  not induce her

Comment: unfortunately that wont be possible you can have a workaround as @topher       is suggesting

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) (emphasis mine):

> The default value must be a constant expression, **not** (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

So only scalar types(boolean, int, string etc), arrays and `null` are allowed.

A workaround could be to check if the parameter is null and set it within the function:

```
function doSomething($year = null) {
    if (!$year) {
        $year = addParameter();
    }
    //actually do something
}
```